# Failed to set image using URL

Tags: java, android, listview, ioexception

I have a custom listView. In my adapter i want to set the image using a url, but i get and IO Exception. For example this is the url, i got from JSON, and it opens up in my browser            `\/\/socialgummers.com\/demo\/tcibuzz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/07\/S054585.jpg`

Now here is the code of my adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(list_resourceID, parent, false);
    final ImageView hotel_pic = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageView_hotel_1);
    TextView hotel_name = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.textview_hotel_1);
    TextView hotel_name_descrip = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.textview_hotel_descrip);
    String hotel = List_Filler.GetbyId(position).getHotel_name();
    String descri = List_Filler.GetbyId(position).getShort_description();
    hotel_name.setText(hotel);
    hotel_name_descrip.setText(descri);
    String temp_url;
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(List_Filler.GetbyId(
            position).getHotel_imgs(), "[\"");
    do {
        temp_url = (String) tokens.nextElement();
    } while (false);
    URL img = null;
    try {
        if (temp_url.length() > 5)
            img = new URL(temp_url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (temp_url.length() > 5) {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            ////Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img.openConnection()
                ////    .getInputStream());
             InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(temp_url).getContent();
             Drawable temp = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "temp");
            hotel_pic.setBackgroundDrawable((temp));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

I tried using the line commented above to get the image but still no luck. I get an exception that says java.io.IOException: Relative path.
Here is my stacktrace:

```
09-27 16:17:19.770: W/System.err(8906): java.io.IOException: Relative path: \/\/socialgummers.com\/demo\/tcibuzz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/07\/S054585.jpg
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:235)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:197)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:613)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at com.tci_buzz.tcibuzz.Hotels_Adapter.getView(Hotels_Adapter.java:70)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1428)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1265)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1128)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8541)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8541)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8541)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8541)
09-27 16:17:19.880: W/System.err(8906):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:903)
09-27 16:17:19.890: W/System.err(8906):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1961)
09-27 16:17:19.890: W/System.err(8906):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 16:17:19.890: W/System.err(8906):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
09-27 16:17:19.890: W/System.err(8906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
09-27 16:17:19.890: W/System.err(8906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 16:17:19.890: W/System.err(8906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-27 16:17:19.890: W/System.err(8906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-27 16:17:19.890: W/System.err(8906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
```

How do i get the image? Thanks.

Comment: The URL is the reason, convert it to `http://ADDRESS/image.jpg` version

Comment: @SebastianSwierczek tried it, it didnt work..

Comment: Maybe it is stupid... but do You have INTERNET permission in manifest ?

Comment: Hahaha well come one Sebastian if i dont have the internet permission i would be getting an UnknownHostException

Comment: your url lacks http:// and all / are escaped using \/ (which is useless in json, btw, tell that to your server guys), which you need to unescape, probably simply by `temp_url = temp_url.replace("\", "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to use: (it should work)

```
        Bitmap temp = null;
        try {
            if (temp_url.length() > 5) {                    
                  temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(temp_url).getContent());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        hotel_pic.setImageBitmap(temp);
```

P.S. You should't do it inside the main thread, move it to AsyncTask.

Remember to provide proper URL in `http://domain` format inside `temp_url` `String` object.

**EDIT : (full code)**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(list_resourceID, parent, false);
final ImageView hotel_pic = (ImageView) rowView
        .findViewById(R.id.imageView_hotel_1);
TextView hotel_name = (TextView) rowView
        .findViewById(R.id.textview_hotel_1);
TextView hotel_name_descrip = (TextView) rowView
        .findViewById(R.id.textview_hotel_descrip);
String hotel = List_Filler.GetbyId(position).getHotel_name();
String descri = List_Filler.GetbyId(position).getShort_description();
hotel_name.setText(hotel);
hotel_name_descrip.setText(descri);
String temp_url;
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(List_Filler.GetbyId(
        position).getHotel_imgs(), "[\"");
do {
    temp_url = (String) tokens.nextElement();
} while (false);


temp_url = "http://" + temp_url.replace("\","");
Bitmap temp = null;
try {
     if (temp_url.length() > 5) {                   
         temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(temp_url).getContent());
     }
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 hotel_pic.setImageBitmap(temp);

 return rowView;
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works for sure. It is problem with Your link to image, try to `temp_url = "http://" + temp_url.replace("\", "");`

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL("http:"+temp_url).getContent();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but i tried this but i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

even if it worked, I'm afraid it won't work the way you want. Due to how a ListView works, by the time you've downloaded the image it may be placed in a wrong row.

Consider using an external library to properly load images, it'll make things easier, specially in ListViews

http://square.github.io/picasso/

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader